# Not receiving Web API HttpResponseMessage in ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

First attempts at Web API and a little confused.

I've set up a basic Delete in Web Api:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(string id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.ReasonPhrase = "User successfully deleted";
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    return response;
}
```

and calling it via jquery ajax:

```
deleteUser: function (data) {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: urlPath + data.Id,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Success: " + response.status + " : " + response.statusText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error: " + response.status + " : " + response.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

This works... Chrome developer tools say StatusCode: 200 User successfully deleted.

Unfortunately the alert from ajax success just says "Success : undefined : undefined", and when breaking inside the success function in Chrome, the response var is blank

How do I retrieve the Status Code/Message in the ajax call to display onscreen?

Thanks

Comment: rather than `response.statusText` try `response.responseText`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters of jQuery's [ajax.success](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback function are:

```
function(PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)
```

As you can see, the first parameter is the raw response body. if you need the HTTP status code and text, use the `jqXHR` (3rd parameter) data:

```
success: function(data, status, xhr)
         {
         alert("Success: " + xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
         }
```